# getting intuition about a fact on probability

Tags: probability

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable.let $L^1$ be the set of all random variables which have finite expectation. My books says that if $X^2 \in L^1$, then $|X| \in L^1$.

My question is: How can we show this? and why is this fact important? or relevant? It seems odd to me to throw this fact if we dont use it. Perhaps it is used later on.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Cauchy-Schwarz.

$$\mathbb{E}\lvert X\rvert = \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[1]}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}( X)^2}=1\cdot \sqrt{\mathbb{E}( X)^2} <\infty$$
where the last inequality uses that $X\in L^2$. This crucially uses the fact that on a space $\Omega$ endowed with a *probability* measure $\mu$, $\int_\Omega 1d\mu =1$. In general (for general measurable spaces), you don't have any relation between $L^1$ and $L^2$, and n particular this argument fails as $\int_\Omega 1d\mu$ can be infinite.

---

As for its use: if a random variable has a variance, then it also has an expectation (this is rather useful), among other things. High-order moments imply low-order ones.